# How to express any irrational number in radicals as a trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers

I'm not even sure if there is an obvious answer or not.

If an irrational expression $A$ in radicals less then $1$ is given, how to express $A$ as a finite trigonometrical expression (not a series).

For example,

$ \frac{1}{\sqrt5} = \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{10}}{1- \sin\frac{\pi}{10}}$

Is there a general algorithm to find such expressions?

UPD: I've checked Niven's theorem on Wiki [1], but it didn't help.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem

Comment: Perhaps you could give a simple example, e.g. how to write a square root as a trigonometric expression?  It can be done in some cases, e.g. $2\sin( \pi/4) = \sqrt 2$, etc., but I'm not sure you are content with such "isolated" examples.

Comment: Both the function integrals and the irrational ones you refer to are beautiful exceptions. The answer to your question is NO but justifying this answer could lead to deep waters.

Comment: @hardmath, yes - my question is if there is such algorithm or proof that there is none.

Comment: @Piquito, could you please share any intuition or your thoughts?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Gauss-Wantzel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon#:~:text=The%20result%20is%20known%20as,Fermat%20primes%20(including%20none).) which describes those regular polygons that can be constructed by compass-and-straightedge.

Comment: @hardmath, I cannot completely see how it would linked with radicals.

Comment: It is linked with square roots and nested square root expressions.  It may not be of any interest to you, but your Question is broadly stated.  To formulate an algorithm, one needs a description of the input to be provided and the output to be accepted.

Comment: @outmind:- First of all try to imagine the most general of the irrationals less (in absolute value!) than $1$, expressed as an expression with radicals. It's terrible. But to make things easier, consider only radicals of the form $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}$ for all $n$. There you just have a problem with no possible solution.Your example with $n=5$ is one of the few exceptional cases. Good luck.

Comment: @Piquito, >There you just have a problem with no possible solution.
Why is it so?

Comment: In fact all algebrical value $\alpha$ less than $1$ in absolute value corresponds to a development of some trigonometrical series, say $\alpha=\sin(\theta)$. The problem is to have a "closed" form for $\sin(\theta)$. I think this is too difficult or impossible.